# How to pass the output from logstash in local machine to Elasticsearch in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash

I want to dump my logstash output to Elasticsearch hosted in AWS. I didn't get any proper documentation online for the same. Please advice.

Here is my logstash message:

```
"message" => "{\"timestamp\":\"Wed Apr 29 18:54:16 PDT 2015\",\"vHost_name\":\"130.65.132.233\",\"cpuUsage\":4438,\"cpuUsagemhz\":2130,\"memUsage\":9235,\"memGranted\":1172063,\"memActive\":359418,\"memConsumed\":1936530,\"diskUsage\":43,\"diskRead\":21,\"diskWrite\":21,\"netUsage\":20603,\"netReceived\":17986,\"netTrasnmitted\":2617,\"sysUptime\":797067,\"sysResourcesCpuUsage\":79}\r"
```

I want to separate every paramater in this and pass to my AWS Elasticsearch instance.

Here is my logstash.conf file:

```
input {
 file {
    path => "/Users/santhirajesh/Desktop/logs/130_65_132_233.log"
    start_position => beginning
    }
 }
  filter {
  grok {match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\|\ %{WORD}\|\ %{GREEDYDATA}]}
  }
  output {
     stdout {codec =>rubydebug}
     elasticsearch { host => localhost }
     }
```

But, this filter doesn't work and I am not getting the values separated like a key value pair. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [grok{}](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/filters/grok) to parse the message according to a format you define.

Use output{} to send it to, among others, [elasicsearch](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/outputs/elasticsearch).

Comment: I m lil confused with the grok filter patterns. I have updated the question with the pattern I tried, but it doesn't work. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The grok pattern must match your input.  Your sample is a bunch of key:value pairs, but your pattern is using pipes ("|").  With key:value input, check out the kv{} filter, though you're still going to want to learn about grok{}.